# How to handle html encoded text in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

In one of our applications, we mainly work with html encoded text on which we want to search.  I could strip the html tags before adding the document to Elastic search (I have a field with the complete text containing the html tags and one without, the stripped version).

I was wondering whether there is a standard analyzer available so that I do not have to strip the html tags "myself", beforehand ...

Hope somebody can be of assistance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [html_strip char filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html) should help:

example :

```
curl -XPOST "http://<server>/_analyze?tokenizer=standard&char_filters=html_strip&text='This%20is%20a%20%3Cb%3EDOCUMENT%3C%2Fb%3E%20with%20html'"
```

Comment: Does this filter needs to be activated or installed or so ?  If I run the above, the analyzed text is "a" "test" "data" "a".  The <a> is thus not stripped; only the "<" ">" and "/" characters are stripped ...

Comment: @cyclomarc strange it works for me. https://www.found.no/play/gist/d3eeb22e1f1b69012f7f#analysis. The html_strip char filter should be available by default.

Comment: Thx @keety.  Does not work in my case. I simply use a post to "_analyze?char_filter='html_strip'" with post body:  "This is a <b>DOCUMENT</b> with html".  Result is a token for "b", "document", "b" and "html".  Any toughts ?

Comment: @cyclomarc i'm able to replicate your issue sorry for the confusion. I have edited the answer,you need to create a custom analyzer using standard tokenizer and html_strip as shown above.